# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec different output format

Tags: java, output, runtime, runtime.exec

I have a simple python program (*hw1.py*) as follows:

```
x = int(input("Enter x value: "))
y = int(input("Enter y value: "))

print("x is " + str(x))
print("y is " + str(y))
print("Output is " + str(x+y))
```

When I run it from terminal, I get following output as expected:

```
Enter x value: 10
Enter y value: 20
x is 10
y is 20
Output is 30
```

However, when I run it from Java with providing inputs ("10" and "20") I get slightly different output. Here is the Java code to compile and run python file:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
boolean isMacOs = osName.startsWith("mac os x");
String macPythonPath = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3";
String unixPythonPath = "/usr/bin/python3";
Process p;
if (isMacOs) {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(macPythonPath + " -m py_compile " + "/Users/inanc/Desktop/pythonDocs/hw1.py");

} else {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(unixPythonPath + " -m py_compile " + "/Users/inanc/Desktop/pythonDocs/hw31.py");  
}

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));


String resError = "", s;
// read any errors from the attempted command
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    resError = resError + s + "\n";
}
resError = resError.trim();
stdError.close();

if (resError.equals("")) {

    if (isMacOs) {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(macPythonPath + " " + "/Users/inanc/Desktop/pythonDocs/hw1.py");

    } else {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(unixPythonPath + " " + "/Users/inanc/Desktop/pythonDocs/hw1.py"); 
    }
    String[] inputs = {"10", "20"};
    OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
    for (String input: inputs) {
        if (input.equals("") == false)
            out.write((input+"\n").getBytes());
    }
    out.flush();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    String res = ""; 
    s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        res = res + s + "\n" ;
    }
    res = res.trim();

    resError = "";
    // read any errors from the attempted command
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        resError = resError + s + "\n";
    }
    resError = resError.trim();
    stdInput.close();
    stdError.close();
    p = null;
    System.out.println(res);
} else {
    System.err.println(resError);
}
```

After calling this code, the output is as follows:

```
Enter x value: Enter y value: x is 10
y is 20
Output is 30
```

How can I get the exactly same output with terminal execution? At least I want to keep the newlines after entering inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, here is the solution:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
boolean isMacOs = osName.startsWith("mac os x");
String macPythonPath = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3";
String unixPythonPath = "/usr/bin/python3";
String filepath = "/Users/inanc/Desktop/pythonDocs/hw1additionalInputs.py ";
Process p;
if (isMacOs){
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(macPythonPath + " -m py_compile " + filepath);

}
else{
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(unixPythonPath + " -m py_compile " + filepath);   
}

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));


String resError = "", s;
// read any errors from the attempted command
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    resError = resError + s + "\n";
}
resError = resError.trim();
stdError.close();

if(resError.equals("")) {


    if (isMacOs){
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(macPythonPath + " " + filepath);

    }
    else{
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(unixPythonPath + " " + filepath); 
    }

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    String res = ""; 
    s = null;
    String[] inputs = {"10", "20"};
    OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();


    for(String input:inputs){
        if(input.equals("") == false)
        {

            Thread.sleep(200);
            while (stdInput.ready() && (s = "" + (char) stdInput.read()) != null) {
                res = res + s ;

            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            Thread.sleep(200);
            while (stdError.ready() && (s = "" + (char) stdError.read()) != null) {
                resError = resError + s;
            }

            if(resError.equals("") == false)
                break;

            out.write((input+"\n").getBytes());
            out.flush();
            res = res + input + "\n";

            Thread.sleep(200);
            while (stdInput.ready() && (s = "" + (char) stdInput.read()) != null) {
                res = res + s ;

            }
            //res = res.trim();

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            Thread.sleep(200);
            while (stdError.ready() && (s = "" + (char) stdError.read()) != null) {
                resError = resError + s;
            }
            if(resError.equals("") == false)
                break;


        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(200);
    while (stdInput.ready() && (s = "" + (char) stdInput.read()) != null) {
        res = res + s ;

    }
    //res = res.trim();

    // this part is for in case of no inputs
    Thread.sleep(200);
    while (stdError.ready() && (s = "" + (char) stdError.read()) != null) {
        resError = resError + s;
    }
    stdInput.close();
    stdError.close();
    if(p.isAlive())
    {
        System.err.println("Timeout");
        p.destroy();
    }
    p = null;
    System.out.println(res);
    System.out.println(resError);
}
else {
    System.err.println(resError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then there is a way only when you make your program such that argument `10` is written to process, then next line is read from the process and then `20` is  written to process, and the another line is read from the process,so on

Whereas, in your code, you are writing all the inputs the process needs in a single loop

Comment: btw, I want it to work with every programs. I may have another program that requires different number of inputs. When I provide necessary inputs, I want it to work as on command line. Can we come up with a generic solution?